# relationship between ANOVA and regression

Tags: regression, anova

Okay, I know this question has been asked many times, and I read other answers but still a bit confused. Other answers mostly mentions ANOVA is just like regression but with categorical variable.

Yet in multiple regression when you do model selection, you can often use a F test and the variables in question don't necessarily all have to be categorical. Furthermore, in R, this is done using the "anova()" function. Is that real ANOVA or is it just a catch all term for F test?

I mean, I get ANOVA is all about analysis of variance and F ratios and all that, but I'm still having trouble drawing connection between, say, the 1 way ANOVA you'd do to test for any significant difference in means among samples of data, VS the model selection that I mentioned above. Can someone explain using analogies? Or a simple toy example to clarify?

Thanks